# How to prove that $11^{n+2} + 12^{2n+1}$ can be divided by $133$ where $n\in\mathbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility

I know that I have to get to a point where an summation is multiplied by $133$ but I don't know how to get there.
I tried formating the equation like $11^2\times11^n + 12 \times 12^ {2n}$ but I got stuck there and I don't really know how to prove it with induction. I really need to solve this.

Thank you for your help and sorry if I misspelled anything. Also sorry that you have to edit it, I don't really know how to make superscripts.

Comment: I assume you're trying induction?

Comment: The question will probably be closed unless you edit the question and show some effort and explain what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't really understand induction so i tried formating the equation like 11*11*11^n+12*12^n and solve it that way but i am stuck. But if you know how, could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: If $n=1$, we get $11^3+12^2=1475$ which is not even divisible by $7$.

Comment: I think you mean $11^{n+1}+12^{2n-1}$ Is that correct?

Comment: If so, then I'll try to give an answer before the q is closed (unless you change it).

Comment: The correct statement is  [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150979/show-that-11n1122n-1-is-divisible-by-133?rq=1). So no need to prove this again.

Comment: Or this : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716789/proving-divisibility-by-using-induction-133-mid-11n2-122n1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Yes, sorry for everyone, i didn't read it right. I fixed it. And also sorry for the bad superscript.

Comment: @WAT that's all right :) Here's a great guide to MathJax (what we use to fornat equations etc): https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seeing as you don't seem to be familiar with induction, I'll give a quick explanation.

We begin by checking the base case for the statement, ie for the first value we are interested in- in your case, check for when $n=1$. Next, we assume the statement is true for some $n=k$.

Next, we use our assumption to show that if the assumption is true then the statement is also true for $n=k+1$. But we already know the statement is true for $n=1$ (in your case), so it must be true for $n=2,3,4,...$ and so on.

I can provide a proof by induction in this case if you feel you are ready for it?

**Proof by induction**
I will make this proof quite explicit as this is your first proof by induction.
First, let $f(n)=11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}$.

*Base case*

Check for $f(1)$:
$$11^3+12^3=133\times23$$
which is certainly divisible by $133$!

*Assumption*

Assume true for $n=k$:
$$f(k)=11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1}\text{is divisible by $133$ for all $k\in\mathbb N$}$$

*Inductive step*

Now to prove that the assumption implies the truth of the statement for $n=k+1$:

$$f(k+1)=11^{k+3}+12^{2(k+1)+1}=11^{k+3}+12^{2k+3}=11(11^{k+2})+144(12^{2k+1})$$
$$=11(11^{k+2}+12^{2k+1})+133(12^{2k+1})=11f(k)+133(12^{2k+1})$$
Now, $133(12^{2k+1})$ is certainly divisible by $133$, but by the assumption, $f(k)$ is also divisible by $133$. Hence we have proved that $f(k+1)$ is divisible by $133$ if $f(k)$ is divisible by $133$. But by the base case, we know it to be true for $n=1$. Hence the result follows for all $n\in\mathbb N$. I'll just formally write the conclusion below.

*Conclusion*

If $f(n)$ is divisible by $133$ for $n=k$ and this implies $f(k+1)$ is divisible by $133$, as $f(1)$ is divisible by $133$ then $f(n)$ is divisible by $133$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ by the principle of mathematical induction.

Comment: Yes I think i got it. If you can provide a proof I would really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: @WAT please see the added proof.

Comment: Thank you very much. You are brilliant.

Comment: @WAT you are most welcome, but I don't think I'm brilliant, rather I've simply been taught this method :)) You can accept this answer if it was very helpful ;)

Comment: Could you help me with some other discrete mathematics problems?

Comment: @WAT I could have a go at them. I'm only in high school myself.

Comment: Is there a way i can reach you? Because I can't post any more questions for 3 days

Comment: I'd prefer not to give any personal details out, sorry. Maybe I'll make an email adress just for maths, I'll tell you if I do.

Comment: Can you give a try to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3946229/if-n100-mod-73-57-and-n101-mod-73-11-then-what-is-n-mod-73-where

Comment: @WAT you can email mathshelper4you@gmail.com for any help with other q's.

Comment: I have sent an email

Answer (score 1):

If you know modular arithmetic, it's easy:

$$11^{n+2}+12^{2n+1}=121\cdot11^{n}+12\cdot144^{n}\equiv121\cdot11^{n}+12\cdot11^{n}=133\cdot 11^{n}\equiv0\bmod133.$$